# Accidentally set "Left Control" as a shortcut to change typing language after updating Ubuntu

Tags: updates, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I Updated Ubuntu and made a critical mistake on key-bindings. I updated everything because I had a problem with a code (I still have it) and it asked me for shortcut to change language.

I gave Left Control (Dumb me) and now I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> etc.. I tried `gsettings reset-recursively` that I saw on a post here but it didn't work.

Any idea how I get to restore the defaults?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88886/discussion-between-pomsky-and-billy-matlock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **(GNOME) Tweaks** to disable this left-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcut. Follow these steps:

1. Install the application by running

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```

   and then launch it.
2. Go to **Keyboard & Mouse** section.
3. Click the "*Additional Layout Options*". A window should appear.
4. Look for "*Switching to another layout*" and expand it. Disable '*Left Ctrl*'.